# Is there a faster way to pass python numpy to java array in JPype

Tags: java, python, arrays, numpy, jpype

Is there any better way to pass a big numpy array to java array in JPype with low memory costing?

Because the data in numpy is so big, which really takes a long time and costs lots of memory.
I also want to save memory, after searcheing in user-guide, it said 'you can pre-convert it once using the wrappers, and then pass in the wrappers'. But I still have no idea.

user-guide: https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#performance

Thanks in advance.

```java
// Java code
public class Demo{
    public int myfit(double [][] trainData){
        // do some things
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```py
# Python code
import jpype
import numpy as np
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())

Demo = jpype.JClass('Demo')
demo = Demo()
# some codes...

train_data = a big numpy array
demo.myfit(train_data)

# shutdown jvm
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Answer (score 0):

Preconverting it means creating a series of `jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble)` and `jpype.JArray(jpype.JDouble,2)` structures copying the data into the arrays. There should be an optimized fill routine for transferring the data once from numpy to Java when it finds the memory view interface, but it doesn't please report it as an issue with the JPype project.  I haven't looked much at the multidimensional versions though as I primarily use it for 1d data currently.

This will cut down the cost if you need to pass the array to Java more than once.  If you are only planning on transferring the data once, then the better solution would be to write a Java support class that loads the data directly from the disk so that object appears in Java directly without having to be stored in Python in the first place.